# Show that the sequence of functions $x(1-x), x^2(1-x), x^3(1-x)...$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Theorem: Let $E,E'$ be metric spaces, with $E'$ complete, and let $f_n: E \to E', n=1,2,3,....$ Then the sequence of functions $f_1, f_2, f_3, ...$ is uniformly convergent if and only if, for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that for any $x\in E$, if $n$ and $m$ are integers greater than $N$, then $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))< \epsilon$

**Question**: Using the above theorem to show that the sequence of functions $x(1-x), x^2(1-x), x^3(1-x)...$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

My proof: Given $\epsilon >0$ and let $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ to be determined laer, and $n,m > N$, $x\in [0,1]$. Define a function $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x)$.

WLOG, let $n>m$. Then,
\begin{align*}
d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))&=|x^n(1-x)-x^m(1-x)|\\
&= |x^m(1-x)(x^{n-m}-1)|\\
&=|x^m| \cdot|1-x| \cdot |1-x^{n-m}|.
\end{align*}

(1). If $x=0$, then $|x^m|=0$. Hence, $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))=0 < \epsilon$.

(2). If $x=1$, then $|1-x|$. Hence, $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))=0 < \epsilon$.

(3). If $x\in (0,1)$, then notice that $lim_{m\to \infty} x^m =0$. By
    definition of limit, for the given $\epsilon$, **there exists an
    $N>0$** s.t. for all $m>N$, $|x^m-0|= |x^m| < \epsilon$. Also note
    that when $x\in (0,1)$, $|1-x|<1$ and $|1-x^{n-m}|<1$. Hence,
    $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))=|x^m| \cdot|1-x| \cdot |1-x^{n-m}| < \epsilon
\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \epsilon$.

So, we can claim that given $\epsilon >0$, **there exists an $N>0$ s.t. for all $k>N$, we have $|x^k-0|= |x^k| < \epsilon$**. And if $x \in [0,1]$, $n,m>N$, then $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x)) < \epsilon$. $\blacksquare$

I think my problem appears in (3) of my proof. When I say that

> For $x \in (0,1)$, we can find an $N$ such that for all $m>N$,
>   $|x^m-0|= |x^m| < \epsilon$.

I have chosen a $x$ before I chose the $N$.

So, can someone write a proof by using the above theorem? I want to see how to use this theorem to prove uniform convergence.

Comment: In the statement of your "theorem" there is no quantification on your $x$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Sorry, do you mean this theorem is wrong? I just copied this theorem from the textbook. I use it to prove the question.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I see what you mean. That said, the fact that "for all $x\in E$" is appended to the end suggests that it "distributes"--that is, it's independent of what comes before it.

I know it's anathema to a careful logician to be so sloppy, but it's fairly commonplace to pull such shenanigans, assuming that the reader will understand what is meant.

Comment: @Cameron Buie So, Let $E,E'$ be metric spaces, with $E'$ complete and let $f_n: E \to E', n=1,2,3,....$ Then the sequence of functions $f_1, f_2, f_3, ...$ is uniformly convergent if and only if, for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that if $x\in E$, $n$ and $m$ are integers greater than $N$ then $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))=0 < \epsilon$. Is that what the theorem says? I think I used this version to prove.

Comment: What LordShark (and I) would like the Theorem to say is this: Let $E,E'$ be metric spaces, with $E'$ complete and let $f_n: E \to E', n=1,2,3,....$ Then the sequence of functions $f_1, f_2, f_3, ...$ is uniformly convergent if and only if, for any $\epsilon >0$ and any $x\in E,$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that if $n$ and $m$ are integers greater than $N$ then $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))=0 < \epsilon.$

Comment: @Cameron Buie Thank you very much! I appreciate it! It greatly helps me because there are many theorems like this in my book.... I'll see how to correct my proof.

Comment: Cameron Buie's statement is wrong. The condition gives pointwise convergence, not uniform convergence because N can depend on x

Comment: @Kavi: Right you are. Dang it.

Comment: Apologies. That should read "the sequence of functions $f_1, f_2, f_3, ...$ is uniformly convergent if and only if, for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that for any $x\in E,$ if $n$ and $m$ are integers greater than $N,$ then $d'(f_n(x),f_m(x))< \epsilon.$"

Comment: @Cameron Buie So, I think I proved the statement based on the correct definition. Would you mind to check my proof? Someone said I only proved the pointwise convergence.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you for your comment. Is it ok to help me verify  the proof?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Your $N$ depends on $x,$ so it proves only pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1):

A simple argument without using any theorem on uniform convergence is as follows: given $\epsilon >0$ choose N such that $(1-\epsilon)^{N}$<$\epsilon$. Let $n>N$. Note that $|x^{n}-x^{n+1}|$ is bounded by $\epsilon$ if $x \geq \epsilon$ and bounded by $(1-\epsilon)^{n}$ if $x<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$. Then
$$
f'(x)=nx^{n-1}(1-x)-x^n=x^{n-1}\big(n(1-x)-x\big)=x^{n-1}\big(n-(n+1)x\big).
$$
Hence, $f_n$ is increasing in $\big[0,\frac{n}{n+1}\big]$
and decreasing in $\big[\frac{n}{n+1},1\big]$ and thus
$$
0=f_n(0)=f_n(1) \le f_n(x)\le f_n\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)=\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^n\Big(1-\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)<\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
Therefore, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $N\in \mathbb N$, namely $N=\big\lfloor\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\big\rfloor$, such that
$$
n\ge N=\Big\lfloor\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Big\rfloor\quad \longrightarrow\quad
n+1>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\quad \longrightarrow\quad 
|\,f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{n+1}<\varepsilon,
$$
and hence $f_n\to 0$, uniformly over the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AM-GM Inequality,
$$x^n(1-x)=\frac{1}{n}\,x^n(n-nx)\leq \frac{1}{n}\,\left(\frac{nx+(n-nx)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}<\frac{1}{n}\,.$$
In fact, this is a plagiarism of my own answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549581/how-do-i-show-f-nx-n2-xn1-x-pointwise-converges-to-0-on-0-1/2549661#2549661), as it works here as well.